# Move a programmatically generated button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a programmatically created button and I want to move it to a different location when a specific method is called. So far I can see the button I created, and I can move a different button that I drag-dropped into storyboard, but I am not sure how I can refer to the programmatically generated button in my code to change its location.

Code for generating button:

```
UIButton *generatedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[generatedButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(genButtonTouched:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
generatedButton.frame = CGRectMake(84.0, 80.0, 70.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:generatedButton];
```

Inside another method, I have code for changing a button's location. If this code is in the same method as where I generate the button it works fine, but I need to place this in a different method:

```
[generatedButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
```

Comment: Create a reference to your generatedButton in header file like UIButton *generatedButton and change the line UIButton *generatedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; as self.generatedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; next change the line as [self.generatedButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];

Comment: add UIButton *generatedButton; to your header file and set frame wherever you want

Comment: @jailanihabeeb No, do not add the instance variable to the header file. Add it in the .m file so it is private. It does not belong in the .h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ButtonViewController.h

```
@interface ButtonViewController : UIViewController{
    }

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *generatedButton;
```

In your ButtonViewController.m

```
@implementation ButtonViewController
@synthesize generatedButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
generatedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[generatedButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(genButtonTouched:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
generatedButton.frame = CGRectMake(84.0, 80.0, 70.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:generatedButton];
}
```

// to call the button anywhere within the class, do like this :-

```
-(void)methodToMoveButton{
[generatedButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
}
```

If you want something else, please let me know.

Comment: It's a bad idea to make `generatedButton` a public property. No outside class should have access to that value. It's also outdated to bother with the `@synthensize` line. And if you are going to create a property you should use it in the code instead of directly accessing the ivar.

Comment: Why outside class cannot use it..?? and Regarding synthesize, i just wrote it, its not wrong anywayz.is it .?? If you have any good solutions kindly edit your answer with that, i would love to learn that.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different than moving the button added in the storyboard. Create an instance variable to hold a reference to your generated button. Then you can access the button in the other method using that instance variable.